# gnome-shell error: Can't update stage views actor

Tags: gnome, 22.04

Edited:

I logged out and back in after about 10 to 15 minutes as advised and see

```
(base) nyck33@nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6:~$ tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopped sandboxed app permission store.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopping PipeWire Multimedia Service...
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopped PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Removed slice User Core Session Slice.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 tracker-miner-fs-3[191242]: OK
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopped Tracker file system data miner.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Removed slice User Background Tasks Slice.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopped target Basic System.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopped target Paths.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopped target Sockets.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Stopped target Timers.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed PipeWire Multimedia System Socket.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed Sound System.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Reached target Shutdown.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Finished Exit the Session.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[191191]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: user@127.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 127.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: user@127.service: Consumed 1.400s CPU time.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/127...
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: run-user-127-doc.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: run-user-127.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@127.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/127.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 127.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: user-127.slice: Consumed 9.071s CPU time.
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 kernel: [114248.910187] kauditd_printk_skb: 1 callbacks suppressed
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 kernel: [114248.910189] audit: type=1400 audit(1671437677.949:1232): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.snap-store" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/discord/discord.desktop" pid=192862 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Dec 19 17:14:37 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 kernel: [114248.934870] audit: type=1400 audit(1671437677.973:1233): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.snap-store" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/discord/discord.desktop" pid=192862 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 kernel: [114249.240755] audit: type=1326 audit(1671437678.277:1234): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=69 subj=snap.snap-store.snap-store pid=192862 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/638/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7f32855d039b code=0x50000
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Builder.desktop/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.clocks.desktop/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Dictionary.desktop/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Documents.desktop/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Evince/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.gedit.desktop/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Maps.desktop/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Weather/* to plugin cache
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snap-store[192862]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 dbus-daemon[192147]: [session uid=1000 pid=192147] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract-3.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=1000 pid=192225 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
Dec 19 17:14:38 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[192123]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Dec 19 17:14:39 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 dbus-daemon[192147]: [session uid=1000 pid=192147] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
Dec 19 17:14:39 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[192123]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Dec 19 17:14:40 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snapd[882]: storehelpers.go:748: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "core", "core18", "core20", "core22", "gedit", "gnome-3-28-1804", "gnome-3-34-1804", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gnome-42-2204", "gtk-common-themes", "kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20", "okular", "slack", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration", "spotify", "vlc"
Dec 19 17:14:41 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 PackageKit: resolve transaction /475_cddeceab from uid 1000 finished with success after 1108ms
Dec 19 17:14:41 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 PackageKit: search-file transaction /476_eadccedb from uid 1000 finished with success after 606ms
Dec 19 17:14:42 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 PackageKit: search-file transaction /477_dabeedcd from uid 1000 finished with success after 336ms
Dec 19 17:14:42 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 PackageKit: search-file transaction /478_daeadebe from uid 1000 finished with success after 332ms
Dec 19 17:14:42 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 snapd[882]: storehelpers.go:748: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "core", "core18", "core20", "core22", "gedit", "gnome-3-28-1804", "gnome-3-34-1804", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gnome-42-2204", "gtk-common-themes", "kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20", "okular", "slack", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration", "spotify", "vlc"
Dec 19 17:14:42 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 PackageKit: search-file transaction /479_daaadcdc from uid 1000 finished with success after 361ms
Dec 19 17:14:43 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 PackageKit: get-details transaction /480_acebdecd from uid 1000 finished with success after 311ms
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: Removed BSSID ac:44:f2:7f:a9:50 from ignore list (expired)
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: Removed BSSID 00:00:00:00:00:00 from ignore list (expired)
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: Removed BSSID ac:44:f2:7d:e9:f8 from ignore list (expired)
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: wlx244bfeada857: Trying to associate with ac:44:f2:7d:e9:f8 (SSID='HotelPivot' freq=5180 MHz)
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437687.9823] device (wlx244bfeada857): supplicant interface state: completed -> associating
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437687.9827] device (wlx244bfeada857): ip:dhcp4: restarting
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 gnome-shell[192585]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 gnome-shell[192585]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: wlx244bfeada857: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=5180 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=1 ch_width=80 MHz cf1=5210 cf2=0
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437687.9913] dhcp4 (wlx244bfeada857): canceled DHCP transaction
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437687.9913] dhcp4 (wlx244bfeada857): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437687.9913] dhcp4 (wlx244bfeada857): state changed no lease
Dec 19 17:14:47 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437687.9913] dhcp4 (wlx244bfeada857): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 19 17:14:48 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: wlx244bfeada857: Associated with ac:44:f2:7d:e9:f8
Dec 19 17:14:48 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: wlx244bfeada857: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Dec 19 17:14:48 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437688.2699] device (wlx244bfeada857): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Dec 19 17:14:48 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437688.2803] device (wlx244bfeada857): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Dec 19 17:14:48 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: wlx244bfeada857: WPA: Key negotiation completed with ac:44:f2:7d:e9:f8 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Dec 19 17:14:48 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: wlx244bfeada857: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to ac:44:f2:7d:e9:f8 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Dec 19 17:14:48 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 wpa_supplicant[889]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
Dec 19 17:14:48 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437688.2947] device (wlx244bfeada857): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Dec 19 17:14:49 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 19 17:14:50 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1671437690.1122] dhcp4 (wlx244bfeada857): state changed new lease, address=192.168.101.5
Dec 19 17:14:50 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=868 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec 19 17:14:50 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec 19 17:14:50 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 19 17:14:50 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec 19 17:14:50 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[192123]: tracker-extract-3.service: Consumed 1.666s CPU time.
Dec 19 17:14:55 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 19 17:15:00 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 19 17:15:08 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 19 17:15:10 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 gnome-shell[192585]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x5645447782f0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Dec 19 17:15:10 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 gnome-shell[192585]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x564544eb5330] is on because it needs an allocation.
Dec 19 17:15:10 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 gnome-shell[192585]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x564544eb7120] is on because it needs an allocation.
Dec 19 17:15:24 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[192123]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Dec 19 17:15:24 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 systemd[192123]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Dec 19 17:15:26 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[192585]: unable to update icon for software-update-available
Dec 19 17:15:26 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[192585]: unable to update icon for livepatch
```

Comment: These seem like normal messages to me. (I assume it is a desktop system.) Please monitor the syslog file for more repeating messages logged _while you are not using your system_.

Comment: @FedKad "while you are not using your system" means close all running processes that were started by me and just monitor it?

Comment: I would log out from the graphical session and wait at least 10-15 minutes. Then log in and look at the period I was logged out.